# Is there a simple way to add a link to Botman replies?

Tags: laravel, chatbot

Perhaps I am not using the right chatbot package for this (botman). I would like to avoid the facebook driver if possible. My ideal scenario is to listen for a question, and spit out a quick response with a link.

```
$bot->reply('click <a href="http://google.com">here</a> for answers.');
```

This renders text only though.

```
// controller code, activated after a hears() match
public function askReason()
    {
        $question = Question::create("If you have questions about $this->town, please visit their community page here:")
            ->fallback('Unable to ask question')
            ->callbackId('ask_reason')
            ->addButtons([
                Button::create('Visit')->value('visit'),
                Button::create('Ask Something Else')->value('continue')
            ]);

        return $this->ask($question, function (Answer $answer) {
            if ($answer->isInteractiveMessageReply()) {
                if ($answer->getValue() === 'visit') {
                    header("Location: http://google.com");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    $this->say('Alright, lets talk about something else.');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Start the conversation
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->askReason();
    }
```

This throws a 405 error when the 'visit' option is chosen and I cannot change the header via xhr. I also tried 'return redirect("http://google.com")'

Does anyone know how to reply in botman with a simple link, redirect, anything other than straight text?

**Edit**
This was my solution. In the chat window that gets iframed in, I added a check for DOMNode insertion and manually added the link.

```
<script>
var ready = true;

// set interval
setInterval(setready, 1000);
function setready() {
  ready = true;
}

$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', "#messageArea", function() {
  if(ready == true)
  {
  setTimeout(replacelink, 200);
  ready = false;
  }
});

function replacelink() {
  $('#messageArea .btn').each(function(){
      text = $(this).html();
      link = text.match(/(Link:)\s(\/[^<]*)/g);
      if(link)
      {
        $(this).html(' ');
        url = link.toString().substring(5);
        text = text.match(/(.*)(Link:)/g).toString().substring(0,5);
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).html('<a href="' + url + '">' + text + '</a>');
        $(this).addClass('linked');
      }
      else
      {
        $(this).addClass('linked');
      }
  });
}

</script>
```

The window seems to reloads every time a message is sent, so the code must run every time (you cannot for instance change the ready check function to look for a class of 'linked' which I tried. I kept it though for css transitions, hiding the buttons until they were linked up.) In the conversation I make the link like so:

```
public function askTown()
    {
        $slug = str_slug($this->town, '-');
        $question = Question::create("If you have questions about $this->town, please visit their community page here:")
            ->fallback('Unable to ask question')
            ->callbackId('ask_reason')
            ->addButtons([
                Button::create('Visit Link: /city/'.$slug)->value('visit'),
                Button::create('Ask Something Else')->value('continue')
            ]);

        return $this->ask($question, function (Answer $answer) {
            if ($answer->isInteractiveMessageReply()) {
                if ($answer->getValue() === 'visit') {
                    $this->say('Glad I could help!');
                } else {
                    $this->say('Alright, let's talk about something else.');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: what if you put it in a value of a button and then redirect using the value of the button that was clicked? Like a call to action button in a conversation pretty much

Comment: Good idea! I have tried this and updated my question as I feel we are closer, but now I get a 405 error.

Comment: What driver are you using at the moment? If you are using something like the web widget, that means your chatframe is an iframe inside your page and I guess that is the problem with the redirect.

Comment: I am guessing you will have to check for that specific button using javascript and redirect when it is clicked if this is the case

Comment: Yes, I am using the web widget. That is also a pretty good idea. Hacky, but I like it! I'll give this a try @LiamRoels

Comment: Can you let me know if it worked for you? I found that I needed to use some hacky solutions when BotMan didn't have the feature implemented yet...

Comment: Yes, I was able to get this working. Very hacky indeed though. I'll update my question

Comment: If you think the resolution you found would be helpful to other users, feel free to [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question. Otherwise, you can [delete your post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue on the front end by inserting a link into the frame with javascript. See my edit for details

Comment: Please post your answer here rather keeping as a part of question.